How can I optimize a SLURM script to use more GPUs for large pre-trained networks and a model using PyTorch?
Our school has a HPC with multiple GPUs and I am trying to figure out how to utilize more of them to run my code faster however I keep running into this error at batch size 128:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rgg2706/Multimodal-Sentiment-Analysis/Models/HHMAFM/src/instructor_tests/train2_test.py", line 260, in <module>
    ins.run()
  File "/home/rgg2706/Multimodal-Sentiment-Analysis/Models/HHMAFM/src/instructor_tests/train2_test.py", line 114, in run
    roberta_text_features = self.roberta(**roberta_inputs_text).last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 835, in forward
    encoder_outputs = self.encoder(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 524, in forward
    layer_outputs = layer_module(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 413, in forward
    self_attention_outputs = self.attention(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 340, in forward
    self_outputs = self.self(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/.autofs/tools/spack/var/spack/environments/default-nlp-x86_64-24072401/.spack-env/view/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py", line 236, in forward
    attention_scores = torch.matmul(query_layer, key_layer.transpose(-1, -2))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 24.00 MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 39.38 GiB of which 9.38 MiB is free. Including non-PyTorch memory, this process has 39.36 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 38.41 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 460.27 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Some important information:

The dataset I am training the model on has 19,600 samples of text+ images

I am using pytorch to feed these features from the pre-trained models through a network

I have run the script with 1 GPU but it takes about 10+ hours

A batch size of 64 works at about 32/40GB of GPU memory


Here is the instructor class I am using:
class Instructor:
    def __init__(self, opt):
        self.opt = opt
        self.train_losses = []
        
        print('> training arguments:')
        for arg in vars(opt):
            print(f'>>> {arg}: {getattr(opt, arg)}')
            
        transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.RandomCrop(opt.crop_size),
            transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))
        ])
            
        mvsa_dataset = MVSADatasetReader(transform, dataset=opt.dataset, max_seq_len=opt.max_seq_len, path_image=opt.path_image)
        opt.num_classes = mvsa_dataset.num_classes
        
        self.train_data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=mvsa_dataset.train_data, batch_size=opt.batch_size, shuffle=True)
        self.dev_data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=mvsa_dataset.dev_data, batch_size=opt.batch_size, shuffle=False)
        self.test_data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=mvsa_dataset.test_data, batch_size=opt.batch_size, shuffle=False)
    
        print('building model')

        self.roberta = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base').to(device)
        self.resnet = models.resnet152(pretrained=True).to(device)
        self.densenet = models.densenet121(pretrained=True).to(device)
        
        self.model = opt.model_class(opt).to(device)
        
        # Use multiple GPUs if available
        if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
            self.model = nn.DataParallel(self.model)
            self.roberta = nn.DataParallel(self.roberta)
            self.resnet = nn.DataParallel(self.resnet)
            self.densenet = nn.DataParallel(self.densenet)
        
        self.reset_parameters()

Here is the run function:
def run(self):
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        params = filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, self.model.parameters())
        optimizer = self.opt.optimizer(params, lr=self.opt.learning_rate)

        max_dev_f1, max_test_f1 = 0, 0
        
        for epoch in range(self.opt.num_epoch):
            print('>' * 100)
            print(f'epoch: {epoch}')
            epoch_start_time = time.time()
            
            self.model.train()
            for i_batch, sample_batched in enumerate(self.train_data_loader):
                batch_start_time = time.time()
                
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                input_ids_text = sample_batched['input_ids_text'].to(device)
                attention_mask_text = sample_batched['attention_mask_text'].to(device)
                input_ids_topic = sample_batched['input_ids_topic'].to(device)
                attention_mask_topic = sample_batched['attention_mask_topic'].to(device)
                images = sample_batched['image'].to(device)
                targets = sample_batched['polarity'].to(device)
                
                print(f"input_ids_text device: {input_ids_text.device}")
                
                resnet_features = self.resnet(images)
                densenet_features = self.densenet(images)

                roberta_inputs_text = {
                    'input_ids': input_ids_text,
                    'attention_mask': attention_mask_text
                }
                roberta_text_features = self.roberta(**roberta_inputs_text).last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]

                roberta_inputs_topic = {
                    'input_ids': input_ids_topic,
                    'attention_mask': attention_mask_topic
                }
                roberta_topic_features = self.roberta(**roberta_inputs_topic).last_hidden_state[:, 0, :]

                outputs = self.model(roberta_text_features, roberta_topic_features, resnet_features, densenet_features)
                loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                
                self.train_losses.append(loss.item())
                
                batch_end_time = time.time()
                print(f'Batch {i_batch} completed in {batch_end_time - batch_start_time:.2f} seconds ({(batch_end_time - batch_start_time) / 60:.2f} minutes)')
                
                if i_batch % self.opt.log_step == 0:
                    dev_acc, dev_f1 = self.evaluate(self.dev_data_loader)
                    test_acc, test_f1 = self.evaluate(self.test_data_loader)
                    
                    if dev_f1 > max_dev_f1:
                        print(f"max_dev_f1: {max_dev_f1}, max_test_f1: {max_test_f1}")
                        max_dev_f1 = dev_f1
                        max_test_f1 = test_f1

                    print(f'loss: {loss.item():.6f}, dev_acc: {dev_acc * 100:.2f}% ({dev_acc:.6f}), dev_f1: {dev_f1 * 100:.2f}% ({dev_f1:.6f}), test_acc: {test_acc * 100:.2f}% ({test_acc:.6f}), test_f1: {test_f1 * 100:.2f}% ({test_f1:.6f})')

            epoch_end_time = time.time()
            print(f'Epoch {epoch} completed in {epoch_end_time - epoch_start_time:.2f} seconds ({(epoch_end_time - epoch_start_time) / 60:.2f} minutes)')
            
        print(f'Max dev F1: {max_dev_f1 * 100:.2f}% ({max_dev_f1:.6f}), Max test F1: {max_test_f1 * 100:.2f}% ({max_test_f1:.6f})')
        self.save_training_loss_plot()

Here is the Slurm script that runs the code:
#!/bin/bash -l

#SBATCH --job-name=${MODEL_NAME}    # Name of your job
#SBATCH --account=${ACCOUNT}        # Your Slurm account
#SBATCH --partition=${PARTITION}    # Run on tier3
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00           # 4 hours time limit
#SBATCH --nodes=1                   # # of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                  # 1 task (i.e. process)
#SBATCH --mem=32g                   # Increase RAM to 16GB
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:a100:3           # 1 a100 GPU
#SBATCH --output=${OUTPUT_PATH}     # Output file
#SBATCH --error=${ERROR_PATH}       # Error file

# Load necessary environment
spack env activate nlp

# Run the main script
cd ${REPO_DIR}/

stdbuf -oL -eL bash ${REPO_DIR}/Models/${MODEL_NAME}/run.sh

I tried running the model with one GPU and it works well but it takes around 10 hours. We have a lot of a100 to utilize at our school so I want to increase performance because the next dataset I train the model on is even larger. A batch size of 64 works but I want to increase it to 128 or beyond to speed up performance but it seems I am running out of memory.

Have you tried to increase #SBATCH --ntasks=1 to, say, 2? It should allocate more cores to your script.
